# How to color the line different between 2 points on borders in maps made with geom_sf and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to make a map, where I would like to color the line between 2 points differently. This sounds a very basic task but I could not find an answer on the web, so I had to post a question here. Let me show what I am trying to achieve with a basic concrete example;

```
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)



turkey_provinces <- ne_states(country = "turkey", returnclass = "sf") # data for turkish cities
ggplot(turkey_provinces) +
  geom_sf() +
  ggthemes::theme_map()
```

which produces this

[image]

What I want to do is, choosing 2 random points on the western border and color the line between them differently. I have tried an approach, where I made a line string and tried to find the intersection with the real border. It was not successful since the shape of the real border is more intricate and finding an intersection with a straight line using `st_intersect` did not work out. So, if you have any suggestion, I am more than grateful for that. Thank you for your attention beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there’s a more elegant solution, but you could define a rectangle bounded vertically by the longitudes you want, and horizontally so that it overlaps the western but not eastern border. Then take the intersection of the rectangle with the border. (Get the outer border using `st_union` and casting to MULTILINESTRING.)

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

rect <- list(matrix(
    c(-85, 35.5, 
      -80, 35.5, 
      -80, 36.5, 
      -85, 36.5, 
      -85, 35.5),
    byrow = TRUE, 
    ncol = 2
  )) |>
  st_polygon() |>
  st_sfc(crs = st_crs(nc))

border_line <- st_intersection(
  rect, 
  st_cast(st_union(nc), "MULTILINESTRING")
)

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = border_line, color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: I do not need elegancy at this point, I just need something to work, so I am more than grateful for your response :). Just one question; how did you make the rect variable in your answer? I could not get that. Can you elaborate on that? You say rectangle but there are five points I am a bit confused. Again thank you so much

Comment: When defining the polygon, the first and last point need to be the same — essentially you’re defining a line that joins up with itself. So matrix includes the lat/long points defining the four corners of the rectangle, then repeats the first point at the end.